# QGIS 3.10.12 An error occurred when executing the query, please check the expression syntax

Tags: qgis, wms, oracle-spatial

When WMS request

> `http://XXXX?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=l_aj_plt,l_aj_lin&TILED=true&FILTER=l_aj_plt,l_aj_lin: ( ( "PASTOVUS" = 'T' AND "AKTUALUS" = 'T' AND 2020 <= 2020 ) OR ( "PASTOVUS" = 'N' AND "AKTUALUS" = 'T' AND "METAI" = 2020 ) ) &SRS=EPSG:3346&STYLES=&WIDTH=1110&HEIGHT=402&BBOX=569501.3671983373,6069913.162089563,570088.7433730897,6070125.887515013`

Is executed I get the result but when I try to add layer `l_aj_plt` as `Oracle spatial layer` in `QGIS Desktop` application and apply filter `( ( "PASTOVUS" = 'T' AND "AKTUALUS" = 'T' AND 2020 <= 2020 ) OR ( "PASTOVUS" = 'N' AND "AKTUALUS" = 'T' AND "METAI" = 2020 ) )` I get the error.

Even if I use QGIS's tools to conctruct simple filter I get the same error
[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't apply the filter?

Comment: And what is `2020 <= 2020` for?

Comment: Same error when no filter applied and pressing "Test". About `2020 <= 2020`  - this not a hardcoded and such filter needs to applied because of data model

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same error/warning when trying to filter a geopackage.
But despite the error message the layer is nevertheless filtered.

```
QGIS version
3.26.3-Buenos Aires Qt version
5.15.3 Python version
3.9.5 GDAL/OGR version
3.5.1 PROJ version
9.1.0 EPSG Registry database version v10.074 (2022-08-01) GEOS version
3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1 SQLite version
3.38.1 PDAL version
2.4.3 PostgreSQL client version unknown SpatiaLite version
5.0.1 QWT version
6.1.6 QScintilla2 version
2.13.1 OS version Windows 10 Version 1809
```

[image: query builder warning]